# After upgrade, creating then getting the record returns null in MariaDB + C# + Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, mariadb, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I upgraded `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` to version `7.0.0`.

In one part of my C# code, I would use `SaveChanges(entity)` to create a record, then I would get that record from a view, using `dbSet.Find(id)` and it was working just fine.

Now the `Find` method returns null.

When I use `set transaction isolation level read uncommitted; select * from TableName` I see that the record is inserted. However, if I simply use `select * from TableName` then that record is not shown.

What should I do? This breaks our entire codebase and we have used this pattern a lot. We insert a record, then we get that record from a view that gets a lot of extra information for it.

Comment: Try add-migration to see if there is a problem with database mapping.

Comment: @sabsab, Nothing is changed in the schema. Thank you for the note though.

Comment: So the migration file is empty?

Comment: We're not using migration (we are db first)

Comment: Then try to scaffold new Models and DB Context. We had problems when we upgraded to EF Core 7. It was because of TPT inheritance changes. But inheritance is not used for Db first as far as I know.